# for - синтаксический сахар?

Tags: любой-язык, for

Задался этим вопросом только потому что нигде не слышал, чтобы его называли сахаром.

Возьмем, к примеру, c#:

```cs
System.Console.WriteLine("Это for:");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}

System.Console.WriteLine("А это while:");
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
        i++;
    }           
} // обратите внимание на 'локальный' блок, вне которого i также, как в for, не определена
```

Мы только что разобрали цикл for на его составляющие и цикл while. С точки зрения результата эти циклы эквивалентны. **Но отличаются ли они на низком уровне?** Если же нет, то for - синтаксический сахар?

В python цикла 'for' вообще нет в привычном его понимании(там по сути foreach). И его можно реализовать только через while. Из-за чего ещё больше кажется, что for - просто сахар, который из некоторых языков вообще выбрасывают.

Comment: Ну, если так смотреть, то while - это синтаксический сахар для goto. По поводу выбрасывают - в каких языках, например? Есть языки где вообще нет циклов в привычном виде, есть только рекурсия. Но в императивных языках все-таки обычно есть отдельно цикл с условием и цикл со счетчиком.

Comment: *С точки зрения результата эти циклы эквивалентны* Вот даже в Вашем исполнении - ни фига не эквивалентны. В коде с `WHILE` переменная `i` всё ещё определена после фигурной скобки, закрывающей тело `WHILE`, до фигурной скобки, обрамляющей локальный блок. А в случае `FOR` добавление аналогичных скобок, обрамляющих локальный блок, не добавит видимости переменной `i` после закрывающей тело цикла скобки.

Comment: Ваш `WHILE` эквивалентен такому `FOR`: `{int i = 0;for (; i < 10; i++){System.Console.WriteLine(i);}}`.

Comment: Точно, забыл про goto.
**в каких языках, например?** 
В python. Там есть for, но у него функционал foreach. 
**А в случае FOR добавление аналогичных скобок, обрамляющих локальный блок, не добавит видимости переменной i после закрывающей тело цикла скобки** 
Да, но синтаксический сахар часто нас ограничивает в чем-то. В данном случае for не позволяет нам зайти в этот блок.

Comment: Я скомпилировал программы с while и for, экзешники по размеру одинаковы, но внутри есть отличая. Сейчас попробую преобразовать в CIL и глянуть что внутри

Comment: @insolor :) а все языки программирования синтаксический сахар для ассемблера или машинных кодов

Comment: @Никита, в python именно такого цикла как в C-подобных языках нет, но никто не мешает сделать `for i in range(N)`, это больше соответствует классическому циклу со счетчиком (как в каком-нибудь Алгол, Паскаль и др. алголопобных языках).

Comment: CIL:   
[while](https://pastebin.com/eAKqmVid)    
[for](https://pastebin.com/7EJj40bc)

Comment: @Никита, для debug версии смотришь? :-)

Comment: @Никита, код одинаковый с точностью до `nop`. Если почитать определение [синтаксического сахара](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Синтаксический_сахар) в Википедии, то можно сделать вывод что да, чисто терминологически конкретно для Си-подобных языков `for` - это синтаксический сахар для `while`. Никто так не говорит скорее всего потому что нет смысла это как-то подчеркивать.

Comment: @Grundy оууу, не знал, что дебаг и релиз отличаются. Пересобрал. [while/for](https://pastebin.com/nPVnVXZk). Код оказался одинаковым! Это победа! Теперь можно с уверенностью говорить, что for - синтаксический сахар. Осталось проверить, сахар ли while. Как указал insolor , возможно это сахар для goto. Если будет не лень, проверю и отпишусь

Comment: А почему не while это синтаксический сахар для for?

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну вообще это только моё предположение. While - проще(под словом 'просто' я имею в виду не ease, а simple), мне он кажется ниже. После for, в скобочках мы указывает команды, которые потом разбрасываются по разным частям кода, если мы это преобразуем в while.

Comment: Машина Тьюринга - настоящий язык, а всё остальное. Сахар. (C)кто-то

Comment: Если `for` и можно назвать синтаксическим сахаром, то только сахаром к более сложной синтаксической конструкции чем просто `while`. Попробуйте увязать сюда `continue`.

Comment: Для `for` в блоксхемах выделена отдельная фигура.

Comment: А машина Тьюринга, в свою очередь, сахар для схемы соединения транзисторов. А транзистор — не более чем определённая схема соединения полупроводников, так что тоже сахар

Comment: Политика — сахар над социологией, социология — сахар над биологией, биология — сахар над органической химией, органическая химия — сахар над общей химией, химия — сахар над классической физикой, классическая физика — сахар над квантовой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` не синтаксический сахар, потому что с ним можно сделать вещи, которые нельзя сделать с while не прибегая при этом к сторонним конструкциям. Например, for позволяет задавать время жизни RAII объектов точно на время работы цикла, например так (код на с++):

```
for (Foo i{0, some_mutex}; i<10; i++){ // Тут класс Foo это RAII который захватит мьютекс и освободит его по завершению цикла. 
    ...
    ...
}
```

Если тут использовать while то пришлось бы городить дополнительное пространство имён.

Comment: В таком случае, это синтаксический сахар для while и блока, верно?

Comment: @VladD мне кажется, что принципиальное отличие тут в том, что с while вам придётся использовать две области видимости, а в for одно. т.е. это уже вопрос выразительности конструкции, а не её удобства. Если сказать, что сахар решает вопросы выразительности то тогда туда попадает весь язык целиком. ИМХО сахар, это конструкции, которые добавляют удобство без изменения выразительности языка.